# How To Create Edit Form To Edit A Data Entry In Django

Tags: django, django-forms

**views.py**

```
def edit(request, question_id):
    questioninfo = Question.objects.filter(id=question_id)
    form = ModelForm(instance=questioninfo)
    return render(request, "questions/edit.html", {"form": form})
```

**models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
question_add_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
question_header = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
question_contetnt = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
question_add_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
question_p_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)


def __str__(self):
    if len(self.question_contetnt) > 30:
        return "[" + self.question_header + "] " + self.question_contetnt[0:30] + "..."
    else:
        return "[" + self.question_header + "] " + self.question_contetnt
```

**urls.py**

```
path('edit/<int:question_id>/', edit, name="edit"),
```

Now when i try to go to edit/2 for example i recive this error:

AttributeError at /questions/edit/65/
'ModelForm' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: You can not simply use a generic `ModelForm`, you need to subclass it for a specific model.

Comment: can you please explain what should i do exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you construct a `ModelForm`:

```
def edit(request, question_id):
    questioninfo = Question.objects.filter(id=question_id)
    form = ModelForm(instance=questioninfo)
    return render(request, "questions/edit.html", {"form": form})
```

But you can not use a `ModelForm` without subclassing it: a `ModelForm` is more a base class that you can subclass to construct a form that works for a *specific* model. We can for example construct a `QuestionForm`:

```
# forms.py

class QuestionForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['question_add_user', 'question_header',
                  'question_content', 'question_add_date',
                  'question_p_id']
```

So here we specify that the form works with `Question` instances, and we also specify a list of fields that are edited with that form.

Now we can use the `QuestionForm` in the view:

```
# views.py

def edit(request, question_id):
    questioninfo = Question.objects.filter(id=question_id)
    form = QuestionForm(instance=questioninfo)
    return render(request, "questions/edit.html", {"form": form})
```

Note that you can change more elements in the `QuestionForm`. For example certain code that should run in case you save a form, or when you validate whether the input is valid. You can also specify that only a subset of the values should be part of the form, etc. But the *default* implementation usually can already define most of the problems you can face when implementing a specific form.